# Is drinking water an important feature for finding habitable exoplanets? Has it been found?

Tags: water, planets, exoplanets

We need drinking water to live on other planets. Has drinking water been found on other exoplanets? Is drinking water an important feature for finding habitable exoplanets?

I want to (self) study in this field and I need some information.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraterrestrial_liquid_water summarises our current knowledge.

Comment: What do you mean by “drinking water”? Do you just mean liquid water? Humans can’t drink from Earth’s oceans, but most of Earth’s animal biomass is ocean animals who can.

Comment: @rob   I mean drinkable by human. or at least, it can be purified by filtering or distillation. The water of ocean can be purified easily and hence it's good for life.

Comment: @mathLover Does ice count? In most of the outer solar system, water ice is functionally a mineral.

Comment: @rob  yes of course.

Comment: In that case, you’re using a different approach than most exobiologists. The wiki link in the first comment has a little explanation about why.

Comment: Are you only interested in exoplanets? Or are you also interested in water in our Solar System?

Comment: @PM2Ring I'm particularly interested in exoplanets. I read a little about Eroupa (moon) and also I saw a documentary about it. I learnt that the other planets in our solar system are not suitable to be habitable.

Comment: Well, some people want to live on Mars, even though its [soil is toxic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martian_soil#Toxicity).

Comment: [Oxygen is the most common element in the universe, after hydrogen & helium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abundance_of_the_chemical_elements#Universe), so we expect water to be available on exoplanets. Even if we develop the technology to travel to exoplanets, it will take a *vast* amount of energy to do so (assuming we don't want the journey to take many tens of thousands of years). The energy required to purify water is quite small, in comparison.

Comment: Isn't this an astronomy question? I think you will get a better answer on the astronomy site. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Note that for the Earth single-celled organisms the freshwater is actually a horrible environment. Even your own blood cell expand and may even explode because of the osmotic pressure when you put them into a potable water. The freshwater protists usually have special pumps that constantly get rid of the excessive water to prevent that.

The freshwater is formed through the mechanisms that means that it's low on various stuff (that's why it's fresh). It's much more likely that life originates in the sufficiently rich solvents to get more complex chemistry happening

Comment: @PM2Ring    Thanks for your interesting information.

Comment: @OON I didn't know about them! Thanks!

Comment: @mathLover, to live on other planets, you need a LONG list of things, including food, water, shelter, clothing, an energy source, a suitable atmosphere, temperatures that are "reasonably" close to what we experience on earth, a very low incidence of chemical or physical compounds that would be deadly to a human, a reasonable surface gravity, plants and animals that you can use to replenish your food supply, suitable conditions for those plants and animals to thrive and reproduce, etc.

Comment: @DavidWhite Wow! I thinks it's better to protect the earth more better! Maybe there is no place out of here for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drinkable Water is H2O that contains the number of dissolved salts and living organisms that a human being needs in order to replenish the water and minerals lost through transpiration, breathing, and other "waste" cleaning processes (e.g. urine production).
For example, on Earth, the ocean water is not "drinkable", actually we have a big issue finding drinkable water resources as many get contaminated or exhausted.

As such, we have not yet discovered drinkable water on other planets.

That said, we may find water resources -in any of the three main phases of matter (solid, fluid, or gas)- that we could adapt to be drinkable, the same we do on Earth when we desalinize ocean water or use condensation to retrieve water from the atmosphere.

Thus our search is for water in any phase, not specific "drinkable" water

And yes, we have already discovered water in many celestial bodies, mostly in the solid form (ice), but it is speculated that other celestial bodies, for example, the moon Europa, may be a Waterworld with a big deep ocean below the ice.

Discovering water on distant stars is done via spectrographic analysis when the planet transits above the remote star.
Some exoplanets have shown signs of water vapor in their atmospheres.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm very interested in knowing more about the exoplanets with water vapor in their atmosphere. A simple link is enough for me.

Comment: Wikipedia could be a good starting point https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_extrasolar_candidates_for_liquid_water

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Drinkable water has not been founded on other planets yet. However, we can probably find liquid water from some planets.

In addition , water of solid phase has been found on Mars, which indicates it is possible that creature lived on Mars in history.

Comment: Hello! It appears to me that you use the terms "drinkable water" and "liquid water" non-interchangeable. What is your distinction between the two, or did I simply misunderstand?

Comment: Yes they are different. Not all liquid water is drinkable. Liquid water usually contains elements that lead to illnesses and is not drinkable.

Comment: But non-drinkable water can easily be purified by filtering and/or distillation.

Comment: That’s true. But it is really hard to remove detrimental elements from water. It requires high level of technology and massive equipment to purify. And It is even a tough thing to transform salt water into drinkable water on the Earth, say nothing of non-drinkable water from other planets.

Comment: Im confused by everyone's confusion. Are we stuck on the difference between water humans are capable of drinking (any liquid water) and water humans could drink without any ill effect (what I would commonly refer to as "drinking water" as found in the question)? This seems like a reasonable and common use of the terms. I dont understand the confusion. Ease of conversion from one form to the other doesnt make the forms the same. You can easily convert solid water into liquid water, it doesnt make them the same, and thats an easier conversion than from non-drinking water to drinking water.

Comment: The OP very specifically said "drinking water" three times. If they were merely asking about liquid water, I'd have expected them to say "liquid water".